# Facing issue with cron on embedded linux

Tags: cron, embedded-linux

I have a SAM9 based board running embedded linux using buildroot package.

I added the `crond` and `crontab` support to busybox from `make menuconfig` and built the rootfs and flashed it to my board.

The `crond` and `crontab` utilities were now present on the board.

I executed the following :

```
mkdir /var/spool/cron/
mkdir /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
crontab -e
```

Then added the following in the editor :

```
* * * * * "harsh" >> /root/harsh.txt
```

Then executed 'crond' and I was able to see it in the list of processes using 'ps' command.

Also the text line with 'harsh' was appeded to the file every minute.

But the problem is that when I reboot the board the `'cron'` directory is deleted from `/var/spool/` and the `cron process` also cannot be started as the `cron configuration file` itself resides in `/var/spool/cron/`

How to fix this ?

PS : I have also posted it on stackoverflow.com here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/9392859/553094 but it seemed to me that serverfault.com is a more approriate place to ask this question

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the directories and crontab(s) in the boot image.

A flash OS unpacks the OS into RAM every time the system boots; there is no persistent filesystem for storage.